# YapDatabase sorting confounds editing update

Tags: ios, uitableview, yapdatabase

In a `UITableViewController` I use YapDatabase with Mantle sorting the following way:

```
YapDatabaseViewSorting *viewSorting = [YapDatabaseViewSorting withObjectBlock:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *group, NSString *collection1, NSString *key1, XQBuilding *object1, NSString *collection2, NSString *key2, XQBuilding *object2) {
    if ([group isEqualToString:XQBuildingsViewGroupName]) {
        return [[object1 name] compare:[object2 name] options:NSNumericSearch];
    }
    if ([group isEqualToString:XQPicturesGroup]) {
        return [[object1 updatedAt] compare:[object2 updatedAt]];
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
YapDatabaseViewOptions *options = [[YapDatabaseViewOptions alloc] init];
options.isPersistent = NO;

YapDatabaseView *databaseView = [[YapDatabaseView alloc] initWithGrouping:viewGrouping sorting:viewSorting versionTag:@"" options:options];
```

Although the used option I have sometimes (when an edited name changes the edited item order in the list) incorrect `indexPath` on reading:

```
    - (UITableViewCell*)editableTableView:(UITableView *)tableView simpleCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        __block XQBuilding *building;
        __block NSNumber *gla;
        [self.readConnection readWithBlock:^(YapDatabaseReadTransaction *transaction) {
            building = [[transaction ext:XQBuildingListYapName] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath withMappings:self.tableViewAnimator.viewMappings];
            gla = [building glaWithTransaction:transaction];
        }];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BuildingCell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = building.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ sqm", formatDecimal(gla)];
        return cell;
    }
```

i. e. `building` in such case is a different one than was edited. How to get a correct `indexPath` according to actual sorting?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things that should be correctly coded to make it work properly!

As I can see from your code you use [`YapDatabaseViewMappings`](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/Views#mappings). Do you use [`LongLivedReadTransactions`](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/LongLivedReadTransactions) and do you subscribe to `YapDatabaseModifiedNotification` to properly modify the table on database changes?

There is an [simplified example that shows](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/blob/aaf17f1c27d3bd1770cd52e42c03c6a31f1c39fa/YapDatabase/Extensions/Views/YapDatabaseViewConnection.h) how to use all these things to update your `UITableView` in real time right after database is updated.